# How to: stream with ffmpeg and nginx rtmp, Ubuntu

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, video-streaming, ubuntu-18.04

nginx installed with https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html in Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo apt -y install curl gnupg2 ca-certificates lsb-release ;
echo "deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` nginx" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list ;
curl -fsSL https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | sudo apt-key add - ;
sudo apt update ;
sudo apt install nginx ;
```

nginx up and running

```
$ ps -aux | grep nginx
root      5602  0.0  0.0  33348   880 ?        Ss   17:03   0:00 nginx: master process nginx
nginx     5603  0.0  0.0  33744  2748 ?        S    17:03   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

with **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;

        application live {
            live on;
            record off;
            allow publish 127.0.0.1;
            deny publish all;
        }
    }
}
```

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc -t 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/test` yields

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, lavfi, from 'testsrc':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[24] / 0x18424752), rgb24, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[tcp @ 0x5611668b8c00] Connection to tcp://localhost:1935 failed: Connection refused
[rtmp @ 0x5611668b8520] Cannot open connection tcp://localhost:1935
rtmp://localhost/live: Connection refused
```

**Clue:**
Nothing seems to be listening on port 1935. `netstat -tap | grep 1935` yields nothing
**Clue2:**
Albeit `ps` shows app as running, `systemctl status nginx.service` shows app status down

```
● nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-12-03 19:37:17 CET; 7min ago
     Docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
  Process: 5709 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Things checked given other stackoverflow questions:

- trying to connect to `rtmp://localhost/live/test` and in nginx.conf the application is correctly named `live`
- nginx.conf correctly placed at /etc/nginx/, no other nginx.conf files exist, and `nginx -s reload` called to make sure it is loaded
- no `localhost` instances in the conf file, all renamed to `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

Install nginx that supports rtmp `sudo apt install nginx-core nginx-common libnginx-mod-rtmp`

and not `sudo apt install nginx`

and then run nginx with
`sudo systemctl restart nginx`